# Save changes to JSON file Android

Tags: android, json, updates

I'm creating an android application for mechanics in a school building. They need to scan the QR code of a room to see if anything is broken in the class room (like a beamer that needs to be fixed). After fixing this, they have the ability to set a checkbox to true to let the other users know that this job is done.

I'm using a json file to get my info, so when the user checks the checkbox, my json file needs to be updated.. I've tried a lot but didn't find a solution for this..

Can someone help me please?

This is what I have know..

```
finished.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                            if (isChecked) {
                                checked = true;
                            } else {
                                checked = false;
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    if (checked) {
                        //JSONObject modified = new JSONObject();
                        try {
                            JSONArray d = new JSONArray();
                            JSONObject tour;

                            tour = new JSONObject();
                            tour.put("done" + (i + 1), "Yes");
                            d.put(tour);

                            String text = data.toString();
                            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("tours", MODE_PRIVATE);
                            fos.write(text.getBytes());
                            fos.close();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        //JSONObject modified = new JSONObject();
                        try {
                            JSONArray d = new JSONArray();
                            JSONObject tour;

                            tour = new JSONObject();
                            tour.put("done" + (i + 1), "No");
                            d.put(tour);

                            String text = data.toString();
                            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("tours", MODE_PRIVATE);
                            fos.write(text.getBytes());
                            fos.close();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to move the code starting from `if (checked) {` inside the listener or into a method you call from within the listener. Checked's value will only change after the click, while you are checking the value at the time you are assigning the listener (= before the click).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
finished.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            String status = "No";
            if (isChecked) {
                status = "Yes";
            }
                // JSONObject modified = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    JSONArray d = new JSONArray();
                    JSONObject tour;

                    tour = new JSONObject();
                    tour.put("done" + (i + 1), status);
                    d.put(tour);

                    String text = data.toString();
                    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("tours",
                            MODE_PRIVATE);
                    fos.write(text.getBytes());
                    fos.close();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                // JSONObject modified = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    JSONArray d = new JSONArray();
                    JSONObject tour;

                    tour = new JSONObject();
                    tour.put("done" + (i + 1), "No");
                    d.put(tour);

                    String text = data.toString();
                    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("tours",
                            MODE_PRIVATE);
                    fos.write(text.getBytes());
                    fos.close();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

    });
```

There is a "status" variable which ll set the status to YES or NO (or whatever data u want to for the json data) when its checked or unchecked